# jquery IF/ELSE statement hover function only firing on second hover?

Tags: jquery, hover

I am using JqueryToolTip to style and animate tool tips for a series of images inside anchors on my page. The problem is that when the tool tip is longer than 30 letters it is not vertically centered inside the div. So I wrote this jquery to add a class of .small to any of the tooltips with less than 30 letters. This produced the effect I wanted except it only works on the second hover. How do I get it to happen on the first hover?

I am still new to jquery. I'm assuming it has something to do with the order I have the code in but i can't figure it out.

```
$("#loop-wrapper a img").hover(function(){
  var getLength = $(this).attr("alt").length;
  if(getLength < 30){
    $(".tooltip").addClass("small");
  }
  else{
    $(".tooltip").removeClass("small");
  }
}, function (){
  $(".tooltip").removeClass("small");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would refactor it to use [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) with a switch parameter, and just one function argument to `.hover`:

```
$("#loop-wrapper a img").hover(function () {
    var getLength = $(this).attr("alt").length;
    $(".tooltip").toggleClass("small", (getLength < 30));
});
```

Comment: this helped a lot, some flickering is gone, but I am still having the same problem. Only on the second hover does the text become centered. I'm pretty sure it's due to the jquerytools tool tip i'm using. here is the code that calls the tool tip

`$("#loop-wrapper a[title]").tooltip({
  position: "bottom center",
  offset: [-18, 0]});`
It then adds a div to the bottom of the HTML markup that has the tool tip, it uses absolute positioning to place the element next to the image